# Xamarin.Android cann't connect iBeacon

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, ibeacon-android

I using this sample application code [iBeacon.FindTheMonkey](https://github.com/MacawNL/FindTheMonkey-Android/blob/master/FindTheMonkey.Droid/MainActivity.cs) and [MultipleBeacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44149877/multiple-estimote-beacons-in-xamarin-android). but my application can't connect iBeacon. I don't know this problem . I need help solving problems this some [mycodeiBeacon.Test](https://github.com/jakarit24/ibeacon/tree/master/test).

Answer (score 0):

That example program is quite old and does not dynamically request COARSE_LOCATION permission as required on Android 6+.  The failure to obtain this permission at runtime will certainly block beacon detections.

I am no expert on Xamarin or the beacon plugin it uses, but here is a blog that shows you how to do this with Xamarin: https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Comment: I try to follow the instructions. add
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

But application can not connect iBeacon like before.

Thank You.